# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE MySQL/PHP issue

Tags: mysql, load

Here is my MySQL table structure

```
id    |   tracking_number   |   order_id
```

Here is the structure of the CSV file:
(Sometimes the order_id is missing, and this seems to be causing issues)

```
"1R2689Y603406","33097"
"1R2689Y603404","33096"
"1R2689Y603414",
"1R2689Y603429","33093"
"1R2689Y603452",
```

Here is my current SQL Query which isn't working:
(The file is being uploaded, and is being read correctly, it's the query itself which is causing issues)

```
        $sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'].'" 
        INTO TABLE table_tracking
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "\""
        LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" 
        (tracking_number,order_id)';

        mysql_query($sql) or die(myqsl_error());
```

What is wrong with my query? Thanks for any help!

Edit: Changed CSV structure to represent missing data that sometimes occurs.
Changed query to match the one I am now using

Comment: What's the actual error you're having? Or the actual unexpected behavior?

Comment: The information doesn't load into the database.

Comment: try mysql_query(...) or die (mysql_error()); and tell us what you see.

Comment: PHP is going to convert the `\n` to an actual linebreak before MySQL ever sees this query, you'd need `\\n` in this case. The default for `LINES TERMINATED BY` is a linebreak anyway, so you don't actually have to specify it.

Comment: Note that MySQL uses forward slashes `/` for filenames, even on windows.

Comment: @Johan: The file path is correct, the file is uploading and being read by the query.

Comment: I think we need more testing. Check with a single row file. Also try importing the CSV with phpmyadmin, maybe it'll tell where it fails.

Comment: @Laurent The issue was that I needed `/r/n` as my line terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying here (not 100% confident) but did you try adding the destination columns like this:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']."' 
     INTO TABLE table_tracking FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (tracking_number,order_id)");
```

You have three columns in your table and are only providing two data.

Comment: You still need to make sure that $_FILES contains a valid filepath with **forward slashes** as required by MySQL.

Comment: @Johan yes. That was the part I was not confident in. kylex: nice :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$sql = 'load data local infile "c:/users/ramon/desktop/1.csv"
        into table test fields terminated by ","
        optionally enclosed by "\""
        lines terminated by "\n"';

mysql_query($sql) or die(myqsl_error());
```

You also probably need to make sure that your third column has a default value.

Comment: i have a reason to belive it's an escaping issue.

Comment: That seems to work except I'm running into an issue. Some of the data is incomplete (missing the order number) and that seems to throw things off.

Comment: You probably just need to put a default value to the field that's missing the data so that its not a prerequisite.

Comment: Actually it appears that I need \r\n as the line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']`, try

```
dirname(__FILE__)."/".$_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']
```

`dirname(__FILE__)` will give the full directory path like 'C:/path/to/directory'.